# The relationship between cyclic connectivity and vertex-disjoint cycles.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

My question stems from the article "M. D. Plummer, *On the cyclic connectivity of planar graphs*" (1972). Before asking my question, the following necessary definitions and explanations are provided.

Let $G$ be a finite simple graph.

- A set of edges $L$ in $G$ is a **cyclic cutset** of $G$ if $G-L$ has two components each of which contains a cycle.
- The minimum cardinality taken over all cyclic cutsets of $G$ is called the **cyclic connectivity** of $G$ and is denoted $\mathrm{c} \lambda(\mathrm{G})$.
- If no such $\mathrm{L}$ exists in $G$, we set $\mathrm{c \lambda}(\mathrm{G})=\infty$.

The author asserts, without proof, the following:

**Assert 1.**  Let $G$ be a 3-connected  simple graph. Then $\mathrm{c} \lambda(G)=\infty$ if and only if $G$ contains no two vertex-disjoint cycles.

I think if-part is easily verifiable. Suppose $\mathrm{c} \lambda(G)<\infty$， i.e. $G$ has a cut set $S$ such that $G-S$ has two components each of which contains a cycle, namely $C$ and $C'$. Obviously, $C$ and $C'$ are vertex-disjoint cycles in $G$. Contradiction.

So we only need to prove that  only-if part：If $\mathrm{c} \lambda(G)=\infty$, then  $G$ contains no two vertex-disjoint cycles. **I don't know how to prove it.** But I know the condition of being 3-connected may be  necessary through the following example,
since the shown graph has $\mathrm{c} \lambda =\infty$, but has two vertex-disjoint
triangles.

[image: ![enter image description here]

But I don't know how to incorporate 3-connectivity into the proof, or **whether changing the condition to minimum degree 3 would suffice**

**Edit:** As  NaturalLogZ and Thomas Lesgourgues remind, the question is easy. In fact, I wrongly thought Plummer considered the cuts being about vertex cuts. My question is based vertex-version.

Does cyclic connectivity have vertex-version? Do we have a similar assert for vertex cyclic connectivity?

Comment: How does your example have $c\lambda = \infty$? Isn't the bridge a cyclic cutset?

Comment: Sorry. At the first, I loss the concept as I thought the cut means vertex cut. I am wrong.

Comment: If $G=(V,E)$ contains two vertex disjoint cycles on edges sets $E_1$ and $E_2$, then $S=E\setminus(E_1\cup E_2)$ is a cyclic cutset. Hence $c\lambda(G)<\infty$.

Comment: I ask a bad question.  Does cyclic connectivity  have vertex-version? Maybe my question is about that.

Comment: You certainly could ask about a vertex version of cyclic connectivity. I don't know if it has been studied before, but I hadn't heard about cyclic connectivity at all before. But even in the vertex version, the strategy of @ThomasLesgourgues should still work. But as with normal vertex-connectivity, it is important that the graph is "big enough" which will be true for 3-connected graphs. Are you aware of  various properties that characterize 2- and 3- connectivity?

Comment: @NaturalLogZ  Thank you.
Inspired by your question, for what value of  $k$, does a 
$k$-connected graph contain vertex-disjoint non-adjacent cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $c\kappa(G)$ denote the cyclic-vertex connectivity of a graph $G$ the statement, "$c\kappa(G)=\infty$ if and only if $G$ contains no two vertex-disjoint cycles" is incorrect. Your example can be modified by connecting each node in on of the triangles to its counterpart in the other (and thus obtaining the skeleton of a triangular prism). This is 3-connected, and for the reasons you have suspected, it should have infinite $c\kappa$.

However, the problem is analogous to the problem that arises when talking about the size of a separating set for adjacent vertices. The difference is you can still easily define the connectivity of the whole graph (as the minimum size of a separating set) so long as the graph isn't complete. And since that is just one family of graphs where talking about vertex connectivity is difficult, you can just define the connectivity of a complete graph to equal the number of vertices.

Thus I would argue that the correct translation of assertion 1 into vertex-cyclic-connectivity would be "$c\kappa(G)=\infty$ if and only if $G$ contains no two non-adjacent vertex-disjoint cycles." (Here two subgraphs $H_1,H_2$ are said to be adjacent if there exists $u \in H_1$ and $v \in H_2$ such that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent.) The proof of this statement is identical to the proof for edge-cyclic connectivity, where the one direction was given by you and the other by @ThomasLesgourgues.

Comment: The graphs where any two cycles are adjacent are interesting! See my new question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464045/graphs-where-any-cycles-are-adjacent